# How increase number of files shown in Recently opened files list?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings

After Eclipse starts I see only 4 recently opened files. Is it possible to see for instance 10 instead?

Comment: where u see only 4 file in eclipse... ex:- which are open ..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You go to

**Window** -> **Preferences**

Then select

**General** -> **Editors**

and you'll find an option that says

**Size of recently opened files list**

which you can change to whatever you see fit.

[image]

Comment: ... as long as `whatever <= 15` :] (at least in Eclipse 3.6)

Comment: Cannot see image in answer (HTTP Connection Failed).

Comment: Sorry about that. My server broke down and I will restore all my images as soon as my provider gets it up again. (Moved files to a temporary server)